# In MATLAB, how do you compare the difference between two rows

Tags: matlab, comparison, row

An input is a data file with ID number of multiple occurrences. (e.g ID# 123) Now what I want is to gather all rows with same ID numbers, compare column by column, and see if what column do they have difference.

Now after that I will move on to the next ID number with multiple occurrences (e.g. ID#456) and do the same.

I repeat everything until I finish with the last ID number of multiple occurrence.

So my output will be like this, 
(1)The column headers will be the same.
(2)The ID# column will have unique entries. Only the ID numbers which have multiple occurrences will be included in this column.
(3)I will add an extra column whose entry contains the number of occurrences the ID number occurred. Example, if it occurred 5 times, the entry is 5.
(4)For, the other columns, if the column has same entries for all the occurrences of a certain ID number, we write "0", else "1". E.g. if for ID#123, the entries in column "Section" is the same for all the occurrences of ID#123, then for our output table, the column "Section" will contain the value of "0". If there is any difference, the output will be "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but I think you want to count the number of unique values and the number of times the unique rows occur. The table below might demonstrate this.

```
+-------+---------+-----+----------+---------------------+
| ID    | Column1 | ... | Column n | num of occurrencies |
+-------+---------+-----+----------+---------------------+
```

This can be done with **[unique](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html)** and **[accumarray](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)**

In the example below, `A` is the original data and `output` is your desired output. The first `n` columns of `output` are your unique data and the last column contains the number of times this row occurred. The row `[1 5]` occurred twice, `[2 3]` once etc.

```
A = [1 5
 1 5
 2 3
 2 4
 3 9];

[k,~,idx]= unique(A,'rows');
n = accumarray(idx(:),1);
output = [k n]
output =

 1   5   2
 2   3   1
 2   4   1
 3   9   1
```